# Unknown encoding

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Does anyone know what kind of encoding is that?

```
\u042e\u043b\u0438\u044f
```

the only thing I know is that this is a name in a non-latin alphabet

Comment: It is possible to operate such strings with something like `while read -n1 char; do printf '\\u%04x' "'$char"; done <<< $(echo -n 'торги'); echo` and `while read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done <app.properties`. Finally i found eclipse plugin "properties editor".

Answer (score 3):

It is "Юлия" (Julia) in Unicode.

Comment: To clarify, this may well be a JavaScript representation of a Unicode string. This worked for me in the Chrome Developer Tools console: `console.log("\u042e\u043b\u0438\u044f")`

Comment: thanks Alexander, do you know how to obtain it with python? I've already tried with encode/decode but with no fortune

Comment: @user1183090 `>>> print(u'\u042e\u043b\u0438\u044f')` should work for you. There is a good [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Answer (score 1):

`\u` is commonly used to indicate numeric Unicode codepoint references, in which case you are dealing with *Unicode*. You can look up their code tables for the precise definitions of the codepoints in question. The [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) on the official website give you an overview of the defined ranges, while [this website](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) lets you search by value.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like UTF-16 characters in the cyrillic block.

```
U+042E CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER YU
U+043B CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER EL
U+0438 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER I
U+044F CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER YA
```

Answer (score 0):

> do you know how to obtain it with python?

In principle `unicode-escape`:

```
>>> '\\u042e\\u043b\\u0438\\u044f'.decode('unicode-escape')
u'\u042e\u043b\u0438\u044f'
>>> print _
Юлия   # dependent on your terminal supporting Unicode
```

However, this only decodes `\u` sequences, and this is very likely not what you actually want to do.

There are *lots* of different languages that us `\u` as a string literal encoding, including JavaScript and Python. Each has slightly different rules about how other `\`-escape sequences work, and potentially around the handling of UTF-16 surrogates. So really you need to know what exact language you are dealing with, and use a parser designed for that language.

JSON is usually a good first guess.

Comment: the problem is that I can't use the print, because I have to manipulate these strings and compare the names with others present in a legacy db...so any idea to obtain the result without the print?

Comment: You have the result. The string `u'\u042e\u043b\u0438\u044f'` *is* the string `u'Юлия'`.